# Converting readlines strings into lists (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to take a list of names and scores, and format them to a dictionary so that if you call the name the scores will be returned.

Each name and score is on the same line of a file like this: 'Marni________7.59 7.24 7.07 4.44 6.52 0.68 4.97 5.97'

I'm having trouble turning each string from the list of lines into its own list(which would be ['Marni', 7.59, 7.24, etc.]. This is what I have so far:

```
sampleDict = {}

def cleanData(initialList,finalList):  
    infile = open(initialList, 'r')
    outfile = open(finalList, 'w')
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for row in lines:
        row.split()
            sampleDict[row[0]] = row[1:]

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I think I can figure out how to actually add the items to the dictionary once I split the lines up into individual lists, but I just can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: `row.split()` returns a new list object, it doesn't change the (immutable!) string object assigned to the name `row`. Try reassigning `row = row.split()`.

Comment: looks like a classmate already asked a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516818/iterating-over-lines-in-a-file-to-check-for-correct-valuespython/26516993#26516993

Comment: It does look like one of my classmates, but they seem to be trying to check the value of the scores instead of associating each name with those scores. And I do have the row.split() assigned in my code, but it's still just coming out as one long string after another.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to separate the name and underscore from the rest of the string. I will assume the underscores are always the same length in this example.

After that, just split the numbers again and store that return value.

```
def cleanData(initialList,finalList):  
    infile = open(initialList, 'r')
    outfile = open(finalList, 'w')
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for row in lines:
        name, numbers = row.split("________")
        sampleDict[name] = numbers.split()

    # Code to sampleDict write to outfile
```